# Javascript function returning array empty

Tags: javascript

When I use the getAll() I am returned with an empty table. I'm pretty sure its skipping everything inbetween the `let filesdir = []` and `return filesdir` because after I push the files I have used console.log and it has logged the files, but I'm not sure why its completely skipping it
[image]
(Image of the directory, I havn't added https to it yet since I havn't bothered to look how to with cloudflare's ssl certifcate)

```js
getAll = async function (directory) {
    let filesdir = [];
    await fs.readdir(directory, async (err, files) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            //console.log(file)
            var filePath = directory;
            if (await fs.lstatSync(path.join(directory, file)).isFile()) {
                filesdir.push('/' + file);
            } else if (await fs.lstatSync(path.join(directory, file)).isFile()) {
                var dd = getAll(path.join(filePath, file));
                dd.then(function (ee) {
                    for (b = 0; b < ee.length; b++) {
                        filesdir.push('/' + ee[b]);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    return filesdir;
};
```

```js
getAll(pathDir).then(function (ee) {
    console.log(ee);
    for (i = 0; i < ee.length; i++) {
        console.log(ee[i]);
    }
});
```

Comment: `fs.readdir` is not a promise, so you can't await it. That's why it takes a callback function.

Comment: do not use then. for obtaining return values, use await instead.

Comment: Or use `fs.readdirSync`

Comment: If you want the promise interface, remember to `require("fs/promises")`, not `require("fs")`. Also, @jiholee, using `.then` is perfectly fine, because that's literally what `async` is for: letting you write a function as normal code, but returning a promise. As `await` cannot (currently) be used in global scope, you _have_ to use `.then()`

Comment: Don't `await` *Sync operations. Use the [Promises API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_promises_api).

Comment: @mike-pomax-kamermans you're talking about notion of promise/async equals fundamentally: that's right and i know it, but what i said about using dd.then without await. so empty array returns.

Comment: @Mike Node has top level `await`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

getAll = async function (directory) {
    let filesdir = [];
    var files = fs.readdirSync(directory);

    for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        var filePath = directory;
        if (await fs.lstatSync(path.join(directory, file)).isFile()) {
            filesdir.push('/' + file);
        } else if (await fs.lstatSync(path.join(directory, file)).isFile()) {
            var dd = getAll(path.join(filePath, file));
            dd.then(function (ee) {
                for (b = 0; b < ee.length; b++) {
                    filesdir.push('/' + ee[b]);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    return filesdir;
};


getAll('./').then(function (ee) {
    console.log(ee);
    for (i = 0; i < ee.length; i++) {
        console.log(ee[i]);
    }
});
// Or
var ee = await getAll('./');
for (i = 0; i < ee.length; i++) {
    console.log(ee[i]);
}
```

Comment: You're making the same mistake as the OP; awaiting synchronous operations that do not return promises. Also, don't wait to add explanation; make that part of the answer from the beginning.

Comment: I just tested my code, that is working well

Comment: This worked however I forgot while testing I chantged the second elseif value to isFile it was originally isDirectory, that however doesn't get returned with everything else., Edit: I added some await infront of getAll() function as defined as dd, and it worked.